# How to show that $\| QA\|_2=\| A \|_2$ where $Q$ is unitary (for a matrix A)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms, unitary-matrices, spectral-norm

I want to show that for a unitary matrix $Q$ and a matrix $A$ that

$$ \|QA\|_2=\|A\|_2$$

I start with the definition of matrix induced norms:

$$\| QA \|_2 = \sup_{x \neq 0}\frac{\|QAx\|_2}{\|x\|_2}$$

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,

$$\| QA \|_2 = \sup_{x \neq 0}\frac{\|QAx\|_2}{\|x\|_2} \leq \sup_{x \neq 0}\frac{\|Q\|\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}=\|Q\|_2\sup_{x \neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}=\|A\|_2$$

since $\|Q\|_2$ and $\sup_{x \neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}=\|A\|_2$ by definition.

This results in $\|QA\|_2 \leq \|A\|_2$. I am not sure how I get the strict equality.

Comment: Do you know about any relation of $\Vert\cdot \Vert _2$ and the trace of a certain function of its argument?

Comment: $$\|QAx\|_2 = \sqrt{ \langle QAx, QAx \rangle } =  \sqrt{ \langle Ax, Q^*QAx \rangle } =  \sqrt{ \langle Ax, Ax \rangle } = \|Ax\|_2$$

Comment: Joel is right. Your proof goes off the rails when you say $\|QAx\|_2\leq \|Q\|\|Ax\|_2$. Use Joel's identity to preserve equality at that step.

Comment: @Joel I think I'm supposed to show it using the definition of matrix induced norms.

Comment: @GitGud I do not know the relation of $\| \cdot \|_2$ and the trace. I do know of a such relation for the Frobenius norm, though.

Comment: But using Joel's comment *is* allowing you to show it using the definition of matrix induced norms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Joel's comment, expanded into an answer. I'm not looking to steal his points, so if he posts an answer, I'll delete mine.
$$\|QA\|_2=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|QAx\|_2}{\|x\|_2}=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}=\|Ax\|_2.$$
Now, this second step obviously requires $\|QAx\|_2=\|Ax\|_2$. But this is easier to prove because we're now working with a vector norm. That is, for any compatible vector $y$,
$$\|Qy\|_2=\left( (Qy)^*(Qy)\right)^{1/2} = \left(y^*Q^*Qy
\right)^{1/2}=(y^*y)^{1/2}=\|y\|_2.$$

Comment: Looks good to me :) +1

Answer (score 2):

In order to go the other direction, you can simply note that
$$
A = Q^*(QA)
$$
where $Q^*$ is unitary.  From there, apply your inequality to find
$$
\|Q^*(QA)\|_2 \leq \|Q^*\|_2\|QA\|_2 = \|QA\|_2
$$